# How to efficiently implement json tcp server and prevent socket flood?

Tags: go

I am searching for most efficient solution, there are a lot of ways to read data from socket and decode json. I obviously should use json.Encoder and json.Decoder, because they are suitable for streaming nature of socket, but I have specific rule to prevent socket flooding, I must close connection if there is a single message > than 5 Kb. My message structure is JSON RPC.

In the following example I can check length and apply policy:

```golang
connbuf := bufio.NewReader(conn)
msg, err := connbuf.ReadBytes('\n')
if len(msg) > 5 * 1024 {
    conn.Close()
}
...
var req JSONRequest
err = json.Unmarshal(message, &req)
...
```

But if client pushes megabytes of data without delimiter, this data will be in application, in msg variable already before server will disconnect client. Pretty vulnerable.

Second example uses Decoder, there is no chance to check size at all.

```golang
dec = json.NewDecoder(conn)
for {
    var req JSONRequest
    if err := dec.Decode(&req); err == io.EOF {
        break
    } else if err != nil {
        log.Println(err.Error())
        return err
   }
   ...
}
```

What is the best approach you can suggest to me? Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at [`io.LimitedReader`](https://godoc.org/io#LimitedReader).

Comment: As Tim Cooper said, but I'll add that if you need the limit to be per message or somesuch you can just implement your own version of `io.LimitedReader` that lets you reset the count/limit between messages or some such. (Or directly change the `N` field as needed).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the first example you can use [`ReadLine`](http://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Reader.ReadLine):

```
connbuff := bufio.NewReaderSize(conn, 5*1024)
msg, isPrefix, err := connbuff.ReadLine()
if isPrefix {
  // too long
}
...
```

If `isPrefix` is true then the line was too long. If you used a `bufio.Scanner` it actually already has a max token size of 64kb.

As Tim Cooper & Dave C said you can use `io.LimitedReader` for the second case, but there's one gotcha with the json decoder. It uses buffered IO, so it will read past the first request.

To fix that use a combination of `io.MultiReader` and `io.LimitReader`:

```
// to start with we have nothing buffered (an empty byte slice)
var buffered io.Reader = bytes.NewReader([]byte{})
for {
    // combine whatever was in buffered with conn, but only up to 5kb
    dec := json.NewDecoder(io.LimitReader(io.MultiReader(buffered, conn), 5*1024))
    var req string
    err := dec.Decode(&req)
    if err == io.EOF {
        break
    } else if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    // we probably read past the message, so save that to buffered
    buffered = dec.Buffered()
}
```

Comment: Answer looking reasonable, I just switched from plain json.Decoder to use your code and received "invalid character 'm' after object key:value pair" error from dec.Decode. Any idea how that happened? Message is guaranteed to be less then 5KB and I even increased limit to 100KB for testing.

Comment: Hard to know without seeing the code/data... When I use `conn := strings.NewReader("{\"a":"b\"}{\"c\":\"d\"}")` and change req to `var req map[string]interface{}` it correctly decodes both objects. Are you sure you're prepending the bytes from `dec.Buffered()` before reading the bytes from `conn`? Also, the decoder will ignore whitespace, but if you have anything else between your objects (`{"a":"b"},{"c":"d"}`) that won't work.

Comment: Yes, sure. I am running it in a goroutine handleClient after AcceptTCP. dec.Buffered() prepended, code is identical. I am accepting this answer because for now I stick to ReadLine solution. Would be good to know what is wrong with 2nd solution. My data is JSON RPC followed by newline. Nothing special. Previous code worked with json.Decoder, but for some reason drop-in replacement does not work.

Comment: Well, one of clients is broken and this is a reason of parsing problems. Excellent answer, thanks.